# Protractor- Store links in a list & click randomly

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to put all the 100 result weblinks of the search engine in a list & then by using a random number generator click on any link randomly.

Below is the code i am trying which isn't working:

```
for (var iterate=1; iterate<100;){
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*4); 
    var i = randomnumber + 1; 
    console.log("Random Number generated for iteration " + iterate+ " is: "+i);
    var link=element.all(by.tagName("a"));
    browser.sleep(3000).then(function(){ console.log('Applied sleep for sometime');});
    link.map(function(links){

    return links;

    }).then(function(links){


    links[i].click();
    })
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `var link` should be `var link=element.all(by.tagName("a"));`

Comment: Thats already been tried @eLRuLL with no result, edited the braces out as per original script.

Comment: also, instead of `map` use `link.get(i).click();`

Comment: ok that worked @eLRuLL . However was wondering why the map function failed in this case ? Any thoughts here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@elRuLL almost answered it in the comments. I wanted to elaborate more on this for all future googlers

`element.all` doesnt return an Array, but it returns an `ElementArrayFinder` object and Protractor API provides special functions to deal with ElementArrayFinder.

[get()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) -

> `element.all(locator).get(index)` - Get an element within the
>   ElementArrayFinder by index.

[filter()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter), [first()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first) so onn... You have to use these special methods to interact with element.all() return. You were incorrectly accessing it using `element.all.[index]`